# Can you order an active record result alphabetical with a specific entry last?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Lets say you have a `Fruit` model and you have a `fruit_type` column:

- bananas
- apples
- oranges
- other
- pineapple

Is it possible to order these like this?:

- apples
- bananas
- oranges
- pineapple
- other

The idea here is I would be building a form select and from a purely UI perspective I want `Other` as the last option.  I am pretty sure I can some some weird code in the view to move `Other` to the end but ideally I would like to return this right from the controller either by a direct order operation or by perhaps manipulating the result of the normal order(:fruit_type) operation to `move` the row that has `Other` to the end.

Answer (score -1):

It's easy to do in Ruby itself and looks pretty simple. Considering your last option is named "Other":

```
other = array.detect { |item| item.name == 'Other' }
array_without_order = array.reject { |item| item.name == 'Other' }
final_array = array_without_order.sort_by(&:name).push(other)
```

Comment: .delete(other) actually destroys that record via SQL vs from the stored result

Comment: final_array = array.reject { |item| item.name == 'Other'}.push(other)

Comment: That will happen if it's a relation, but not an array. I'll update accordingly.